# Ctrl-del works differently

Tags: windows-10

I delete words with Ctrl-Delete. But if you have a couple of words followed by a comma, then the word will get deleted but the comma won't (unless you hit Ctrl-Delete again, of course).

So one could say Ctrl-Delete stops at punctuation.

But since a couple of days it doesn't do that anymore. It will the delete the word with the trailing punctuation. Annoying. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Many people mistake the format of this site to be that of a forum. It is a Q&A site for specific questions to be answered. Taking a [tour] will help you understand how the site works. You have asked a rather ambiguous question; "*Anyone has experienced this?*" Did you mean to ask how to resolve the issue described?

Comment: CharlieRB, I have changed "Anyone has experienced this" to "How can I solve this". Is that better?

Comment: Great edit. Was there a particular application this happens in (Word, Excel, email, browser)? Or is the behavior system wide?

Comment: Just about every application. I'm wondering why it changed all of a sudden. Could this be OS related (W8 to W10)?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate what you are seeing on my system. Sorry, I have not been able to find anything on why this would happen. The only thing I could suggest would be to use system restore back to a date prior to the issue starting to see if that resolves it.